# Windows 10 IOT Core Default Password

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

What is password for Windows 10 IOT Core Dashboard if i installed the Windows 10 IOT Core ( 10.0.16299.15) through the NOOBS?

Comment: When I google I get p@ssw0rd...Did you try searching the internet?

Answer (score 5):

I found following password is useful.

p@ssw0rd

p@ssw[zero]rd

Answer (score 3):

if you had not set any password initially while installing Windows IoT to your flash SD card, it would remain as the defaults, i.e.,

`Username: Administrator
Password: p@ssw0rd`

If you had entered any password initially while installing Windows IoT using the Windows IoT dashboard utility, then the password would change to that,

`Username: Administrator
Password: xxxx_your_set_password_xxxx`

Answer (score 1):

OK, Found the solution! You need to connect with the computername in front of the username...like this...

```
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName minwinpc -Credential minwinpc\Administrator
```

Yes, the command line should be in this form:

```
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName <machine-name or IP Address> -Credential Administrator
```

Please also note that the default password is: `p@ssw0rd`

The zero can easily be mistaken as an 'O' so calling that part out.

Answer (score -2):

I found User Name : Administrator
     and Pass Word: (as I fill in on Windows 10 IOt core Dashboards) ,could not use p@ssw0rd .